# why Clock: can't known any way access to the hardware clock.?

Tags: linux, clock

When I type in clock command to check the hardware clock, reminder
Clock: can 't known any way access to the hardware Clock.
who can solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Neither ̀`Clock` nor `clock` is an available command on my Linux/Debian (and `aptitude search clock` don't mention any `clock` program). The standard POSIX command to get the [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and [date](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/date.html) is [date(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) so you can just type `date` (or `/bin/date` if `/bin/` is not in your [$PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29)); perhaps you have tried [hwclock(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/hwclock.8.html)

Your question is too imprecise. You could [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) your `Clock` command to understand what is happening.

You need to read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) to understand the various notions of time on Linux and POSIX.

Most Linux systems are connected to the Internet, or to some [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) server. Then their time would automatically adjusted by some appropriate NTP client (which would call [adjtimex(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/adjtimex.2.html) appropriately)

Perhaps your [RTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_clock) chip is giving time in local time, but your Linux system expects a GMT time (or vice versa). This is configurable (perhaps in `/etc/adjtime`).